# Driver cores must be a positive number

Tags: apache-spark

I have upgraded Spark from version 3.1.1 to 3.2.1.
And now all existing Spark Jobs break with following ERROR.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Driver cores must be a positive number
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.error(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:634)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.validateSubmitArguments(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:257)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.validateArguments(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:234)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.<init>(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:119)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2$$anon$3.<init>(SparkSubmit.scala:1026)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.parseArguments(SparkSubmit.scala:1026)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:85)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1043)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1052)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

We are using Spark in cluster mode with apache mesos and co-located with cassandra.

I tried few options:

```
e.g. appl/spark/bin/spark-submit --name "Testjob" --deploy-mode cluster --master mesos://<master node>:7077 --executor-cores 4 --driver-memory 1G --driver-cores 1 -class ....
```

Do you have any hints or solutions for solving this problem.

Many thanks...
cheers

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I think it is impossible to run Spark 3.2.x with Mesos in Cluster mode because of [this feature](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-35013) and the way MesosClusterDispatcher works.
Basically what's happening the Dispatcher is submitting the Spark Application with the --driver-cores argument as a floating point number, and then Spark (SparkSubmitArguments.scala) reads it as String and parses it just like this:

```
driverCores.toInt
```

and of course this fails.

I proposed a [quick fix](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/37016) for this but meanwhile I just built the code with the change I made in the PR. I also reported this as a [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-39617).