# Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Driver cores must be a positive number

Tags: apache-spark, driver, mesos, spark-submit

I have problem with submit task in Mesos with cluster mode, first I using this syntax to running cluster mode on Mesos

```
$ cd spark
$ ./sbin/start-mesos-dispatcher.sh --master mesos://10.2.3.95:5050
```

After that I submit task in Mesos using spark-submit

```
./bin/spark-submit --master mesos://10.2.3.95:7077 \
                   --deploy-mode cluster \
                   --name scraping_twitter_1.py \
                   --py-files ~/scraping/scraping_twitter_1.py \
                   --driver-cores 4 \
                   --total-executor-cores 8 \
                   --conf spark.master.rest.enabled=true \
                   ~/scraping/scraping_twitter_1.py
```

And then problem like this
[image]

I already changes the spark-submit script to run this task
I already try to add

```
--driver-cores 4 \
--driver-memory 10G \
--executor-cores 4 \
--executor-memory 10G
```

But the result is still same
**Driver cores must be a positive number**

The task run well
[image]

I also open http://10.2.3.95:8081/ to see the log
[image]

Comment: The same problem was raised here,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71691292/driver-cores-must-be-a-positive-number